# How do I hide a div containing an entire table if table only has 1 row?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

Fairly new to JS and html. I tried using this function and I'm not seeing results. Would appreciate some help. Here is the JS code and the html div and table where it would be used.

```
    function emptyTableRedisplay(table, uRowsMin)
    {
        if (! table || ! table.rows || table.rows.length >= uRowsMin)
            return;

        let styleHide = table.getAttribute("data-hide-style");
        if (! styleHide || styleHide === "")
            return;

        let idAlt = table.getAttribute("data-alt-id");
        if (! idAlt || idAlt === "")
            return;

        # find the enclosing div
        let el = table.parentNode;
        while (el && el.tagName.toLowerCase() == "div")
            el = el.parentNode;
        if (! el)
            return;

        var alt = el.parentNode.parentNode.getElementById(idAlt);
        if (! alt)
            return;

        el.classList.add(styleHide);
        alt.classList.remove(styleHide);
    }
```

In the html, this is what I did

```
<div id='emptyTableRedisplay'>                  
<h3>Header</h3>
<p>Notes</p>
<table class='data-table monetary' data-final-rows-to-not-sort='0' data-hide-style='1' data-alt-id='2'>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th class='sortable-col' data-collation-form='0-9'>Box #</th>
<th class='sortable-col'>Box Name</th>
<th class='sortable-col' data-collation-form='0-9'>Reported</th>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The JS code you've provided is looking for things that don't exist in the given HTML. For example, you get the parent node of the table here `let el = table.parentNode;` but then you start looking for that div's parents `while (el && el.tagName.toLowerCase() == "div")`. Do you need an element other than the immediate parent of the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if table row length is equal to 1, if so then you hide the div

```js
const emptyTableRedisplay = document.getElementById("emptyTableRedisplay");
const tableRows =  document.querySelectorAll("#emptyTableRedisplay tr");
if (tableRows.length === 1) {
  // uncomment the line below
  // emptyTableRedisplay.style.display = "none";

  //Just for demo
  emptyTableRedisplay.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue"
}
```

```html
<div id="emptyTableRedisplay">
  <h3>Header</h3>
  <p>Notes</p>
  <table class="data-table monetary" data-final-rows-to-not-sort="0" data-hide-style="1" data-alt-id="2">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th class="sortable-col" data-collation-form="0-9">Box #</th>
        <th class="sortable-col">Box Name</th>
        <th class="sortable-col" data-collation-form="0-9">Reported</th>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but if the goal is to hide the table if there is one row you can execute this function onLoad:

```
function emptyTableRedisplay() {
    const table = document.getElementById('emptyTableRedisplay');
    const rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr');
    if(rows.length == 1) {
        table.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

If you will be adding and removing rows after loading you will need to use an event listener instead.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply do this:

```js
const tbl = document.querySelector("#emptyTableRedisplay table");
if(tbl.rows.length==1) tbl.closest("div").style.display = "none";
```

```html
<p>Before the div</p>
<div id="emptyTableRedisplay">
  <h3>Header</h3>
  <p>Notes</p>
  <table class="data-table monetary" data-final-rows-to-not-sort="0" data-hide-style="1" data-alt-id="2">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th class="sortable-col" data-collation-form="0-9">Box #</th>
        <th class="sortable-col">Box Name</th>
        <th class="sortable-col" data-collation-form="0-9">Reported</th>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<p>After the div</p>
```